# Subflow passing record as an input not working as expected

Tags: visual-workflow, variable, cross-object, subflow

I have a flow calling a subflow to which i pass an account record:
[image]

The AccountrecordID is a record variable (Account type).
In the subflow, when i want to eveluate its related records, for instance AccountrecordID.relatedrecord__r.anyField__c, the value returned is null.

My question is: Does passing a record as input in a subflow only passes the record itself without its related records and if no, is there something that can be done in the setup to allow related records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing only the Account Record to the subflow here. If you want to access the related record, you should query that record and implement certain logic within the subflow.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation @Hariprasath